# Horizontal scrollbar for images in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am developing a web-site for mobile and i-pod in HTML. I would like a horizontal scroll bar for multiple images in one row, which has a hyper link.

What is easiest method for this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: All people answering questions here are volunteers. If they answer your question, they do this solely to help you. How about showing them some respect by taking some care when writing up your questions and stopping your ridiculous textspeech? This also has the advantage (for you) that well-written question tend to get more and better answers.

Comment: am i wrong some where?...plz correct me...because i m using this method 1st time so its obvious that i will b wrong some where...so plz help me frnd...

Comment: First thing to do is not to speak in text speach contractions, such as plz and 'b'. We shouldn't have to take the time to parse your question, becuase you didn't take the time to write it properly.

Comment: We're asking you to type out complete words, don't use this ugly short-hand. Instead of "frnd", type "friend". Instead of "plz", type "please". It doesn't take long, and conveys a sense of professionalism and care which is completely absent in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

This example has inline styles, please put all your style rules into a stylesheet when you actually use this code.

Here is an example of the HTML you need...

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 120px; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="width: 1000px; height: 120px">
        <ul style="padding: 0;">
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
            <li style="display: inline;"><img src="image.png" alt="My Image"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```